# R Shiny using Html Template from SB Admin 2 - Dashboard

Tags: html, r, templates, shiny

I was trying to create dashboard using HTML template taken from SB Admin 2 - Dashboard [taken from here](https://startbootstrap.com/themes/sb-admin-2/)

Also, I was following this tutorial https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html. Before i add {{ headContent() }} and {{ bootstrapLib() }} on the head section the generated dashboard become smaller as can be seen on the picture.
[image]

I don't know why, does anyone here know? I guess it is because different version of bootstrap and js. But I am not sure how to make generated dashboard exactly like the template before.

Comment: After some digging into discussion about bootstrap 4 in shiny. I cant found any solution to use any template that utilise bs 4. It is because shiny by default still using bootstrap 3. So i decide to looking for template that use bootstrap 3.